# WKB form substitution for V

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

If I have the equation $$y'' +\sin(1/x)y = 0$$ how would I replace $\sin(1/x)y$ in order to get epsilon squared in front of the first term? I have tried defining $X= \delta\sin(1/x)$, but that doesn't help at all. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.7.iii

Answer (score 0):

At least for large $x$ we can approximate $\sin(1/x)\approx 1/x$ to get

$$y''(x)+\frac{1}{x}y(x)=0$$

Which can be solved in terms of Bessel functions:
$$y(x)=c_1 \sqrt{x}~ J_1(2\sqrt{x})+c_2\sqrt{x}~Y_1(2\sqrt{x})$$

They admit asymptotic expansions for real $x$
$$J_\nu(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\left[\cos\left(x-\frac{\nu \pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+O(|x|^{-1})\right] $$

$$Y_\nu(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\left[\sin\left(x-\frac{\nu \pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+O(|x|^{-1})\right] $$

Meaning in our case

$$\sqrt{x}~J_1(2\sqrt{x})\asymp \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}x^{1/4}\left[\cos\left(2\sqrt{x}-\frac{3 \pi}{4}\right)\right]$$

If we give the two equations identical initial conditions at $x=1$ we can see the fit is already quite good:

[image: plot]

I'm afraid however around the origin the behavior is extremely hard to model due to the very fast oscillation of the sine term. Hopefully this is a good start.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and for walking me through the steps. When you say Bessel function, that isn't WKB form, is it? Doesn't that require that the leading order term (y'') have a squared epsilon in front of it?

Comment: @user490808 I'm pretty inexperienced with WKB, this was just my own approach to the problem. I'm not sure how to modify the equation to put it in WKB form.